# how to Get audio output chanel and audio track in python vlc

Tags: python-3.x

I try to make a player in python 3 with libvlc to make the player with playlist, audio track, and audio output channel options, but i have trouble using the documentation. I hope someone can help me to :

- make a playlist,
- get and set audio track,
- and set auido channel

thanks,

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import keyboard
import vlc

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        Form.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.NonModal)
        Form.setEnabled(True)
        Form.resize(1024, 720)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(Form.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        Form.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        Form.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(1024, 720))
        Form.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(1024, 720))
        Form.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(Form)
        self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1024, 720))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.frame.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.frame.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.frame.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(1024, 720))
        self.frame.setStyleSheet("QFrame{\n"
"background-color: rgb(38, 38, 38);\n"
"    }")
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.instance = vlc.Instance()
        self.au = vlc.AudioOutputChannel()
        self.media = None
        self.mediaplayer = self.instance.media_player_new()
        playlist = (r"C:\Users\masdika\Downloads\videoplayback (3).mp4", r"C:\Users\masdika\Downloads\600548.mp4")
        self.media = self.instance.media_new(playlist[0])
        self.mediaplayer.set_media(self.media)
        self.mediaplayer.set_hwnd(int(self.frame.winId()))
        self.mediaplayer.play()
        keyboard.add_hotkey("space",self.butt)
        keyboard.add_hotkey("l",self.audioleft)
        keyboard.add_hotkey("r",self.audioright)
        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)
        #self.audio()

    def butt(self):
        if self.mediaplayer.is_playing():
            print("pause")
            self.mediaplayer.pause()
        else:
            print("play")
            self.mediaplayer.play()

    def audioleft(self):
        print("L")
        self.au.AudioOutputChannel.Left()

    def audioright(self):
        print("R")
        self.au.AudioOutputChannel.Right()

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

i read in documentation to change audio output channel is use AudioOutputChannel class but i fail to try this and make the error.